# Min Max Default Quantity for WooCommerce new product default to allow selling below minimum

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need new products to default to allow selling below the minimum when the stock level is below that minimum value.

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'myWoo_allowSell', 10, 3);

function myWoo_allowSell($postID, $post, $update) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'alg_wc_pq_min_allow_selling_below_stock', 'yes');
    }
```

Here's the code I'm attempting, which should be pretty simple, but it's adding it as a custom field in the product edit page instead of checking the appropriate box. I've noticed that when I inspect the checkbox element it gives me alg_wc_pq_min_allow_selling_below_stock_ followed by a different number each time I refresh the page. I believe this is why I'm not getting it to work, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this one out on my own. I fixed the meta tag and added the !$update qualifier.

```html
add_action('save_post_product', 'myWoo_allowSell', 10, 3);

function myWoo_allowSell($postID, $post, $update) {
    if (!$update) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_alg_wc_pq_min_allow_selling_below_stock', 'yes');
    }
}
```